# Shotgun doesn't start after updating to Ruby 3.0.1

Tags: python, ruby, server, sinatra, upgrade

I'm trying to start Shotgun for a Sinatra app after having upgraded to Ruby 3.0.1, and get this:

```
 $ shotgun 
== Shotgun/Thin on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:11:in `run': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9.2/bin/shotgun:156:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/shotgun:23:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/shotgun:23:in `<main>'
```

Running `gem list`,  I get:

`shotgun (0.9.2)`

What's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby v3.0 introduces a **breaking change**, relating to keyword vs positional arguments.

The `shotgun` gem hasn't been updated for a long time; the latest version (0.9.2) was released in September 2016.

Looking at the gem in github, I see there's an [open issue](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/issues/75) about this exact problem you've raised, and someone has already - helpfully - [forked the project with a fix](https://github.com/delonnewman/shotgun/commit/762eae9e4eac5babdc4e3e0cea1beeeb427638ea).

Unless the original author merges this fix and releases a new version of the gem, you'll need to use a forked version such as the above. For example, update your `Gemfile` to say:

```
gem 'shotgun', git: 'https://github.com/delonnewman/shotgun.git'
```

And then run `bundle install`.

There's also [this open PR](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/pull/74) with the exact same fix, so you could equally use that fork instead.

---

... Or alternatively, stick to ruby `2.7` for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, I should've checked the GitHub issues. Using the forked version doesn't solve the problem in any way, so I guess I'll stick to Ruby 2.7.1 for now.